# Eclipse/Subversive: How to commit always on Eclipse exit?

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subversive

I wonder if (and how) it is possible to always automatically commit a repository once Eclipse is closed?

I didn't find any option in the Eclipse "Team" preferences.

Comment: alright, so let's leave this question here if anyone wants to do the same thing s.t. he founds out that it's in most cases not a good idea.

Comment: btw. using subversive this might not make sense, but e.g. with eGit it might be a good idea to locally commit each time and only push once you know that your commit was fine/finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ever do that. Committing should be done when

- code compiles
- unit tests pass
- the change you're committing doesn't make your colleagues go mad because the code is in such a state that they can't do their work anymore

Moreover, the commit might very well fail if someone else has made a conflicting change, forcing you to update and perhaps made additional changes before trying to commit again.

In short, it's not something that should be automated at the closing of Eclipse (and that's why Eclipse doesn't allow to do it and probably never will).

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a very bad idea indeed, as JB pointed out.

Without knowing why you'd want to do that, maybe using Eclipse ["local history"](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm) feature would be more suitable?